# Select jobs where time is greater than 30 mins with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm facing a problem and need your suggestions on this.

I have a form where the user can select the delivery time for their job. the options are from 1 to 29 days.

for example, the user has select 3 days for his job. When the job will be active it should show 3 days for the delivery time then on the next day it should show 2 days and so on and when there are 0 days left I want to hide the job post.

I have tried to make my SQL query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM jobs 
 WHERE status = active 
   AND job_expiration > $current_time
```

I'm using timestamps for the job expiration.

`$delivery_time = date('U') + ($job['delivery_time'] * 24) * 60 * 60;` like so.

`$job['delivery_time']` will be a number between 1 to 29.

I am converting that to milliseconds to enter in the database. then to show the time I'm converting the milliseconds to days

`round( $job_expiration / 3600000 / 24 )` like so.

Here is how my Jobs table looks like:

```
id
int(11)
auto_increment

posted_by
varchar(255)

title
varchar(255)

delivery_time
int(11)

job_expiration
int(11)

date_posted
int(11)
```

With the code above it still shows the job with 0 days left. how can I solve this?

Comment: include table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE jobs`. [date and time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions will make this easier.

Comment: also store an absolute date, rather than number remaining. number remaining can be an expression when queried.

Comment: `WHERE job_expiration > NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` or any other unit like `NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE`. Better store job_expiration as DATETIME.